# Bash Regex for empty string returns true

Tags: regex, bash

```
if [[ " " =~ ^[0-9]*$ ]]; then echo "si"; else echo "no"; fi; //Echoes No

if [[ "" =~ ^[0-9]*$ ]]; then echo "si"; else echo "no"; fi; //Echoes Yes
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is as expected. You specified 0 or more times (`*`) a digit (`[0-9]`). An empty string is 0 times that.
Use a `+` (which means "1 or more times") instead of a `*`:

```
if [[ " " =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then echo "si"; else echo "no"; fi; // Should echo No
if [[ "" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then echo "si"; else echo "no"; fi; // Should echo No
```

Comment: Thanks I completely forgot about these basics.

Answer (score 2):

The first one is a space, which does not match the `[0-9]*` regex.

The second is empty, which is `[0-9]*` because `*` also implies 0 ocurrencies. If you make it match at least one ocurrency with `+`, then it is false:

```
$ if [[ " " =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then echo "si"; else echo "no"; fi;
no
```

Answer (score 2):

`*` in a regex means "0 or more", so with nothing in the target string, the regex trivially matches.

Answer (score 2):

`[0-9]*` matches *zero* or more digits, so yes, it matches the empty string. If you don't want to match the empty string, use `[0-9]+`, which matches *one* or more digits.